# Populate CreatedOn, ModifiedOn columns

Tags: wpf, sql-server, wcf

I am building a WCF service with a SQL Server, which will be consumed by a WPF app. I want my database tables to have columns like:
CreatedOn, CreatedBy, LastModifiedOn, LastModifiedBy

Is there a way to create these authomatically, or if not I can create them, but is it possible somehow their values to be populated by SQL server?

Thanks

Comment: This is easy to do with triggers. Do you have any preference about whether the modified columns reflect the created columns until another modification has been made, or do you want those to be `NULL` until first update? Also is the username you want to store based on the application, or is it the SQL/Windows auth username? I am just not sure if WCF has the ability to actually ignore columns in the table.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Aaron. The modified columns should be the same as the created columns. The usernames are stored in a custom table.

Comment: So if the usernames are app-specific then SQL Server is only going to update those columns if it knows who called the stored procedure. It's only going to know that if you pass that into the stored procedure that handles the insert/update, so you'll need to make modifications for that. If you remove all the `SUSER_SNAME()` parts from my script, it will handle the date/time for you, but you won't be able to audit the usernames without modifications to your DML.

Answer (score 1):

Made a couple of assumptions here - that `CreatedBy`/`ModifiedBy` would be populated with a system variable such as `SUSER_SNAME()` and that modified values should reflect the same values as created, initially. Assuming this base table:

```
USE tempdb;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.foo(fooID INT PRIMARY KEY);
GO
```

Make these modifications:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.foo ADD CreatedOn SMALLDATETIME 
    NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

ALTER TABLE dbo.foo ADD CreatedBy NVARCHAR(32)
    NOT NULL DEFAULT SUSER_SNAME();

ALTER TABLE dbo.foo ADD ModifiedOn SMALLDATETIME 
    NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

ALTER TABLE dbo.foo ADD ModifiedBy NVARCHAR(32)
    NOT NULL DEFAULT SUSER_SNAME();
GO
```

Now you just need a trigger to handle subsequent updates:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.foo_audit
ON dbo.foo
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM deleted)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE f
            SET ModifiedOn = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                ModifiedBy = SUSER_SNAME()
            FROM dbo.foo AS f
            INNER JOIN inserted AS i
            ON f.fooID = d.fooID;
    END
END
GO
```

If you need the username to be passed in from the app, then WCF is going to have to help with that.